# Python structure operators clarification

Tags: python, data-structures

I've come across a snippet of Python code that I may want to adapt to Java for a personal project, but am having some difficulties understanding the operations.  The snippet contains the following:

```
F={}
for stage in range(4):

  if stage == 0:
    F[stage]=[]
    i=0

    for j in range(i, len(words)+1):
      F[stage].append([cost(i, j), 0])
```

Here, `cost` is an external def that takes in two integer values and returns a math operation.

From what I know, `F={}` intializes a dict, which is analogue to the Java HashMap, and `[]`denotes the initialization of a list.

First, am I correct that `F[stage].append([cost(i, j), 0])` means to

- take the integer value of the `cost` function,
- create a list with two values and
- append it as a single container to the end of the F[stage] list?

Secondly, this line part following the code above has me stumped.

```
if F[stage-1][i][0] + cost(i, j) ...
```

The way I'm interpreting it is

- `F[stage - 1]` retrieves the list at the location
- `[i]` accesses a sublist container and
- `[0]` retrieves the value at the first index location of the sublist

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you please include the code for `cost`?

Comment: The Python code you've shown is really confusing. For example, it loops over four stages, but does nothing for 1-3... I'm not sure you really want to be duplicating it, unless there's a bunch more that you've cut out.

Comment: @Blckknght, there is a bit of code that I didn't include.  What I'm trying to do here is understand what the data structure operation is relative to Java.  In essence, this question is more of a Python data access and retrieval question than code clarification.

Comment: Can you at least show the rest of the loop? Your second line with `F[stage-1]` isn't included in your snippet up top, so I have no idea what it means in context.

Answer (score 2):

The line you are asking about,

```
if F[stage-1][i][0] + cost(i, j) ...
```

seems to be looking at a cost calculation from a previous stage; it seems almost like a pathing algorithm looking for the best next move. The reason why I say it's a cost calculation from a previous stage is (obviously) the `stage-1` index, and also the fact that when `[cost(i, j), 0]` is appended to `F[stage]` (a list), the `[0]` element of that list is `cost(i, j)`. So you're right to say that "`[0]` retrieves the value at the first index location of the sublist" but it may help to know that it's also specifically retrieving an earlier cost result.

In Java, it might be more idiomatic to use a small class instead of the 2-item list for cost and whatever the second parameter is, with appropriately named fields and accessors.

You would also be fine using an array instead of a dict for `F`, since although the Python code uses a dict, it treats it like an array by only accessing numeric stage keys 0-3.

I'm wondering if we're missing some of the context that you wish to convert, though, especially as the `if F[stage-1] ...` line is not included in the original snippet.

Comment: There is a bit of code that I didn't include. What I'm trying to do here is understand what the data structure operation is relative to Java. In essence, this question is more of a Python data access and retrieval question than code clarification.

Answer (score 1):

First, am I correct that F[stage].append([cost(i, j), 0]) means to

take the integer value of the cost function,
create a list with two values and
append it as a single container to the end of the F[stage] list?

---

Your understanding is correct. F[stage] would be a list of lists.

---

The way I'm interpreting it is

F[stage - 1] retrieves the list at the location
[i] accesses a sublist container and
[0] retrieves the value at the first index location of the sublist

---

It seems to me that 
F[stage] is a list of list, of that structure:
[[what cost(i, j) returns, 0], [what cost(i, j) returns, 0]....]
Since here i is 0(or does it change?)
F[stage-1][i][0] refers to the last stage's cost(0, 0)
It seems to be adding the cost of some last stage to the current stage to determine something.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track of the comments you made in the understanding of the python code.  Of course it depends on the context of what that code is doing.  But as for the Dictionary / List structures of Python you can start w/ a simple dictionary like this

```
>>> tst = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> tst
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

now replace the value of 'one' w/ a nested list

```
>>> tst['one'] = [1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3]
>>> tst
{'two': 2, 'one': [1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3]}
```

now to get to the 'c' in the nested list

```
>>> tst['one'][1][2]
'c'
```

and you could take it even a step further by adding more nested array's.  If I am not mistaken any list in Python can become a "jagged array"